# IBM Cloud - Unable to add Analytics Engine from catalog

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud

I have an old trial account in Bluemix, I tried to add "Lite" version of Analytics engine, but the subsequent page to configure the service doesn't allow me to do anything. There is nothing in the drop down and create button is disabled. Even the Manage button on right hand top corner is disabled. There is no error or any message displayed as to why I can't configure the service.
[Screenshot of the bluemix catalog page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nCVN.png)

Comment: I wasn't able to do it yesterday either, it seems to be working fine toady. Can you check if it's back for you?

Comment: yeah, it worked for me today without any change. Probably it was just temporary maintenance unavailability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that your trial account expired some time ago. Lite accounts are a fairly new approach to giving you access to a service within certain limits. You have two options:

- Submit a ticket to ask for your account to be converted from a Trial Account to a Lite Account. However, not all Trial accounts are compatible with a Lite account and might not be converted. This [page](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/get-support/howtogetsupport.html) describes how to submit a ticket.
- Create a new account using a different email address. It will be created as a Lite account as a result of the registration process.

Comment: Where can I find more info on Lite account (what is the difference between Lite and Free)? Are all new accounts going to be Lite accounts?

Comment: These account types are described in the the Account types topic within the IBM Cloud platform documentation here: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/account/index.html#accounts